# How to adjust the cell size to the frame of a plot?

Tags: plotting, export

I have this Mathematica code to plot two histograms and their PDF fits,

```
<< eNpop.dat;
    Arand = Map[Sort, eNpop, {2}];
    AArand = Cases[Arand, {_, _, _, _, _}, 2];
    A1rand = N @ Flatten[Map[(#[[1]]) &, AArand]];
    << eFPSpop.dat;
    Afps = Map[Sort, eFPSpop, {2}];
    AAfps = Cases[Afps, {_, _, _, _, _}, 2];
    A1fps = N @ Flatten[Map[(#[[1]]) &, AAfps]];
    e\[Phi]1rand = 
     FindDistribution[A1rand, TargetFunctions -> "Continuous", 
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
    A1fps = N @ Flatten[Map[(#[[1]]) &, AAfps]];
    e\[Phi]1fps = 
     FindDistribution[A1fps, TargetFunctions -> "Continuous", 
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];

    dibA1 =
 Show[
  Legended[
   Histogram[<|"RAND" -> A1rand, "FPS" -> A1fps|>, {10}, "PDF", 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 350}, All}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
    ChartStyle -> 96, 
    ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[None], Opacity[0.25]], 
    FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Probability"}
    ],
   Placed[
    LineLegend[96, {"No stigmergy", "FPS"}, 
     LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 12}], {0.85, 0.85}]], 
  Plot[{Callout[PDF[e\[Phi]1rand, x], 
     StringForm[
      "FrechetDistribution(\[Alpha]=0.9, \[Beta]=65.3, \[Mu]=-6.7)"], \
{150, 0.0055}, 120, CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint"], 
    Callout[PDF[e\[Phi]1fps, x], 
     StringForm[
      "0.7 CauchyDistribution(a=48.3, b=13.2) +\n0.3 \
InverseGaussianDistribution(\[Mu]=419,\[Lambda]=604.7)"], {143, 
      0.012}, 60, CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint"]}, {x, 0, 350}, 
   PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> All], ImageSize -> 600]
```

The datasets `eNpop.dat`and `eFPSpop.dat` can be downloaded from

[this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8l1au2vtu1vz0xv/datasets.zip?dl=0)

The problem is that the cell of the generated figure is bigger than the frame of the picture. I would like to adjust the cell of the figure to the frame.

[image]

Comment: Is your data essential to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have other types of plot with this data and do not have this problem so I think the datasets are not important. For example, with the same datasets I make.

Comment: `Show[SmoothHistogram[{A1rand, A1fps}, Frame -> True, Filling -> Axis, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"No Stigmergy", "FPS"}, {0.85, 0.7}], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 300}, All}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Opacity[0.45], {Black}, Dashed], 
    Directive[Thick, Opacity[0.75], {Red}]}], ImageSize -> 600]` and there is no space arround the frame of the picture and the cell in the notebook is adjusted to the size of the frame.

Comment: I have changed the position and text of the `Callouts` and the space around the frame is bigger now (above main code).

Comment: Can you please show a *minimal* but *complete* example?  See http://sscce.org/ and [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/12) for guidance. The question should include code for exporting (or a description of how you export), preferably a screenshot of the result, and clear description of what is undesirable about the result, and what you want instead. A further problem with the question is that you seem to have incorrect assumptions about how cell sizing works. Cell sizing should not matter at all when creating figures.

Comment: I tested your code. A screenshot would have made this much more clear.  I do not understand why this happens, but a (somewhat inconvenient) fix is to specify the `ImagePadding` manually in `Show`.  For example, `ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {35, 10}}`.  Be careful not to accidentally cut off any labels.

Comment: You may also want to report this behaviour to [Wolfram Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/) (please do). It does not seem to be correct. It may be a bug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56534/discussion-between-user1993416-and-szabolcs).